# Need to select all tables from a database in SQL Server where the most recent date-timestamp is from a year or more ago

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datetime

I'm going through all tables in a database trying to determine which tables are old (have not been altered in a long time). I've been going through and flagging all tables with old DTS's as "old"

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Can I run a statement that scans all tables in a database for date-timestamp fields and then looks at the most recent ones?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: We need to know how you're “going through all tables” now before we can suggest better ways.

Comment: I've done something similar with ColdFusion and redbrick.  I queried the system tables to get the tables I needed, then looped through the results running the appropriate query during each iteration.  The reason it worked is that all the applicable fields had the same name.  If I tried hard enough, I could do the same thing with sql server and coldfusion, or even .net.   That means other people could as well.

Comment: I'm looking at the list of tables in each database, selecting the top 1000 rows from each table (going in alphabetical order), locating a date-timestamp field in each table, and then selecting the MAX date-timestamp and if that value is earlier than 1-1-2014, I consider it "old"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view to retrieve all the tables having the timestamp column (assuming the column name is known and not used for other columns).

Use these to generate Dynamic SQL of the form

```
SELECT COUNT(*) ,@TableName FROM @TableName WHERE @TimeStampColumn < @TimestampToCheck
```

The tables where count(*) is 0 are the ones you need to look at

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

Show a COUNT(*) of rows written in the last year... if you get 0, you know the table isn't in use.

Use the information_schema to get the columns/tables.

```
SELECT 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS ['+TABLE_NAME+'] FROM ['+TABLE_CATALOG+'].['+TABLE_SCHEMA+'].['+TABLE_NAME+'] WHERE '+COLUMN_NAME+' > DATEADD(YY,-1,CONVERT(DATETIME,FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT,GETDATE()))))'
-- SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE DATA_TYPE='DATETIME'
--AND (COLUMN_DEFAULT='(getdate())' OR COLUMN_DEFAULT='CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
```

You can add the last line in, if you only want columns with a default value.

Then take the output, copy to a new window, and run it!